# Conversion SSI to SPI

Tags: spi, transceiver, rs422

I want to interface an encoder based on the SSI interface with a microcontroller and only an SPI interface is available (I can't use other interfaces than SPI). As far as I see, SSI has a lot in common with RS422. I wonder if it is possible to convert RS422 to SPI.

What do I mean?

I would connect `CLK` to `DI`, `MISO` to `RO` and CS to `DE` and `RE` with a transistor which allows to put two elements into High-Z state at once.

The IC below is a [MAX491](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX1487-MAX491.pdf).

[image]

Is it possible at all? What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

You would need a converter board, as the SSI isn't just hardware layer protocol, it has also a protocol layer. If you are doing serious things, then you might be interested in SoC or MCU with these protocols already implemented, like Renesas Cortex R4, TI Sitara,...

EDIT:

[Note on SSI and MCU](https://www.posital.com/media/posital_media/documents/AbsoluteEncoders_Context_Technology_SSI_AppNote.pdf)
As from note, the SSI can be implemented with SPI pretty straightforward. Perhaps you would need an isolated RS422 transceiver rather than using MAX IC. The app. note describes hot to use DATA galvanically opto isolated and CLK non-isolated. Nowadays you have isolators and PSU all in one IC, see [MAX14858](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX14856-MAX14858.pdf) or [ADM2582E](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/adm2582e_2587e.pdf) for example.

Comment: Hi Marko. The MCU is already selected and it hasn't been selected by me. The encoder neither. I need to connect it at the lowest cost.

Comment: Which MCU? See edits.

Comment: I use an STM32F446

Comment: I decided to add a MAX3491 transceiver. I'll see how the things go.